# Verify id and title in url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, clean-urls

I have website which have some data that need to be shown securely.
data table should like this

```
id      title       slug
---------------------------
1       some title  some-tilte
2       other too   other-too
```

currently i am accessing data via id. for example `www.example.com/auth/some-title`

But now requirment is to verify id with title for security purpose. so how can i call url like `www.example.com/auth/some-title/id`

```
e.g
www.example.com/auth/some-title/1
```

i try by route in codeigniter

```
$route['rj/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'rj/single/$1/$1';
```

i know it is not proper way to do but can you guys please help to verify id with my title slug.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

At first study [URI Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html) of Codeigniter.

Here is the usages example of uri class -

```
$this->uri->segment(n)
```

Segment function allow you to retrieve a specific segment form URI string where n is a segment number.Segments are numbered from left to right.For example,if your URI like codeigniter uri segment

```
http://www.domainname.com/index.php/blog/language/php/function
```

By the above example URI segment function give result by n parameter.

```
echo $this->uri->segment(1);//it will print blog
echo $this->uri->segment(2);//it will print language
echo $this->uri->segment(3);//it will print php
echo $this->uri->segment(4);//it will print function
```

> And to secure your ID -> you may encrypt your ID

Set Encryption key to your application/config/config.php, open the file and set:

```
$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY";
```

Initialize [Encrypt class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encrypt.html) in controller `$this->load->library('encrypt');`

Now Encrypt your ID `$encrypted_ID = $this->encrypt->encode($ID);`

Now Pass it through your URL without know worry.

When your URL is Called with the Title and encrypted ID then ->

```
$encrypted_ID = $this->uri->segment(n); // n is the position of your ID in url
```

decode it `$plain_id = $this->encrypt->decode($encrypted_ID);`

Answer (score 1):

In my app i route like this.

```
$route['sub_folder/controller/method/(:num)'] = 'sub_folder/controller/method/$1';

// or

$route['sub_folder/controller/method/(:any)'] = 'sub_folder/controller/method/$1';
```

you can try something like

```
$route['controller/method/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/method/$1/$2';
```

your method may look like:

```
public function single($page, $verify){

}
```

hope that helps

Comment: but how can i get `$1/$2` ?

Comment: As long as your method accepts 2 arguments. one for page and other for verify should be fine

Comment: i updated my answer with an example method that would work with this technique